# Understanding inequalities and how not to blindly apply famous inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality

> If $x \in (0, \pi/2)$, prove that
>
> $$ 2 (\sin x )^{(1-\sin x)} \cdot (1-\sin x)^{\sin x} \leq 1 $$

#### Attempt:

We use Youngs inequality: if $\alpha+\beta = 1$ and $x,y $ are positive, then $x^{\alpha} + y^{\beta} \leq \alpha x + \beta y $.

In our problem, both $\sin x$ and $1 - \sin x$ are positive thus,

$$ 2 (\sin x )^{(1-\sin x)} \cdot (1-\sin x)^{\sin x} \leq 4(1 - \sin x) \sin x   \;\;\;\;\;\;\; (*)$$

If I let $f(x) = 4 (1-\sin x) \sin x$ then $f'(x)=0$ implies that $x= \pi/6$ is a max and since $f(\pi/6) = 1/4$, we are done.

Is this a correct argument?

MY question is: We could have also use the AM-GM inequality in (*) to obtain that

$$ f(x) \leq 8 ( (1-\sin x)^2 + \sin^2 x ) $$

But this would us lead us nowhere since the above is bounded above by $40$. Why does the AM-GM inequality gives such large bound for $f(x)$? How do we know when to apply AM-GM inequality properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first solution is correct. It becomes a bit simpler to read with the substitution $u = \sin(x) \in (0, 1)$:
$$
 2u^{1-u} (1-u)^u \le 4 u(1-u) \le 1 \, .
$$

The first estimate is Young's inequality (as you noticed), this is also a special case of the [Weighted AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality).

For the second estimate you determined the maximum by computing the derivative, but actually it is just the AM-GM inequality: $\sqrt{u(1-u)} \le \frac{u + (1-u)}{2}$.

Since equality holds for $u=1/2$ (corresponding to $x = \pi/6$) the inequality is sharp.

---

Your second approach has two errors: First, AM-GM in the form $2ab \le a^2 + b^2$ gives
$$
 4 u (1-u) \le 2 \left( (1-u)^2 + u^2 \right)
$$
with the factor $2$ on the right-hand side, not $8$. Second, you did not consider that $0 \le u = \sin(x) \le 1$. In this range we have 
$$
 2 \left( (1-u)^2 + u^2 \right) = 4 \left( u - \frac 12 \right)^2 + 1 \le 2 
$$
with equality for $u=0$ and $u=1$. This gives the  estimate
$$
 4 u (1-u) \le 2 \left( (1-u)^2 + u^2 \right) \le 2
$$
which is better than your result but not sharp, because equality cannot hold simultaneously in both estimates.

Generally, when applying multiple inequalities, it is good to keep track of when *equality* holds. The end result is only sharp when equality can hold in all estimates simultaneously.